# Using Xpath to Selecting HTML text between two different elements on page

Tags: html, xpath

I have a page with the following structure:

```
<h2 id="about">About</h2>
<p style="margin-top: 0px;" >a bunch of text</p>
<p class="contactAdvisor"><a href="http://www.domain.com"></a></p>
```

I'm trying to select all the text in the 2nd paragraph (eg. a bunch of text)

I have tried:

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h2[id='about'] and following sibling::p[class='contactAdvisor']]
```

However, I am getting nothing in return.

Sample URL: http://www.aplaceformom.com/community/1777-haslett-road-apt-142119

Not sure why this doesn't work. I've tried using the xpath both in Google Sheets using Importxml function as well as in Screaming Frog as a custom extraction

Comment: attributes need to have an `@` before them - otherwise they are assumed to be child elements. try `//p[preceding-sibling::h2[@id='about'] and following sibling::p[@class='contactAdvisor']]`

Comment: You can get the text from the <p> tag just by using below simple xpath,

.//h2[@id='about']/p[1]

Comment: @KeithHall syntax for following sibling is also wrong, it should be "following-sibling"

Comment: @SudharsanSelvarj good spot - I didn't notice that :) I'm guessing it's a typo in the question (and my copy-paste comment), otherwise the OP would have received an XPath syntax error I think

Comment: Thanks everyone! Sometimes you get bug-eyed staring at something.  Good pick @KeithHall - I had the "-", just forgot to type it.  Keith & Suharsan Selvarj - perfect - it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the following `xpath` as well :-

```
//p[not(child::*)]

//p[preceding::h2[@id = 'about'] and not(child::*)]

//p[preceding::h2[@id = 'about'] and following::p[@class = 'contactAdvisor']]

//p[preceding::h2[@id = 'about']][1]

//p[@class = 'contactAdvisor']/preceding::p

//h2[@id = 'about']/following-sibling::p[1]

//h2[@id = 'about']/following::p[1]

//h2[@id = 'about']/following::p[not(child::*)]
```

Hope it helps..:)